# Change the Dynamice created Div Id When i Remove the revise Div

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When a dynamically added Div is removed, the sequence of their id is interrupted. For example, when DivId no. 1,2,3, 4 have been added on the page, and location no. 2 is removed, the remaining location ids on the page becomes no. 1,3,4. This needs to be updated to read 1,2,3 after removal.

Comment: Can you share how you are dynamically adding and removing a div.

Comment: update the id's after deletion..

Comment: check this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/s8nxygae/. Are you want this type of output?